# Upload images using FTP and show them in media

Tags: images, media

**Hello,**

This weekend one of my websites was hacked and all photos was removed (the folder uploads). That means the images in my site doesn't work. :( I had a backup of that folder and I have recovered it.  but the images are missing in the media from Wordpress, I can not manage them and also no all images are displayed but are in the folder.

Are there any way to show the imagen in media? or I should upload one by one all images?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's one year old but just in case someone else is also searching: You could upload the main files (not all 3 sizes, just the original images) via FTP to another directory on your server and then use the [Add-From-Server Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/).

Comment: This is the only solution I've found that is reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the plugin [Add From Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) hasn’t been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress, so we get a warning

> It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility
>   issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.

As an alternative, you can use [Media Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/). Make sure you untick the selectbox *Dry Run (test without making database changes)* when you're ready to import (in the following image is selected, so that won't do database changes and, therefore, [you won't see the images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/360398/110842))

[image: Dry Run from Media Sync]

Answer (score 0):

While uploading an image via media uploader, WP automatically makes at least 3 additional sizes for different purposes. So You have to manually upload all images one by one.

Comment: I had a backup of that folder, so all images had that 3 additional sizes.. I resolved the problem uploading ALL images via media on WP and adding all images in all pages and post... so many hours of work..:( Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it is right.

Comment: I can not mark it as accepted because didn't help me to solve my problem.. I uploaded the backup of the folder "Uploads" that I had and the images wasn't in media to manage them.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your uploads folder permission. if its not 777 then do it 777 may be it would help you..

Comment: That's not the correct permission for the upload folder. If there is a registered PUT handler on the server, everybody can place any file in that directory. A very bad idea!