# uploading files to the uploads folder via ftp

Tags: uploads, media-library

What is the reason/s that the WordPress
Media Folder, doesn't display  images that were uploaded via FTP, directly to the uploads folder? Why doesn't WordPress "see" them? why do we always have to upload via the WordPress media uploader? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because WordPress is not scanning all the folders all the time. When you upload images Wordpress also makes an entry in the database, records the caption, the sizes that are available and so on.

Comment: o.k interesting, but why doesn't is scan the "uploads folder"? can we "make" it scan the "uploads folder"? (sorry for my english:(

Comment: Sure, that's possible, see @BorisKuzmanov 's answer. But that will leave the database without a lot of information, such as captions and so on, although these days the exif information inside the image can be used for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin [Add From Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) that allows you to select files from the "uploads" folder and import them in the Media Library.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a file using the default WordPress media uploader, it saves the file information inside the database. So, when you see them in Media, it means they exist and are registered in the database.

When you use other method to upload the image, like FTP, the database isn't automatically populated and, therefore, WordPress won't recognize their existence.

Answer (score 0):

[Media from Ftp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-from-ftp/)
and [Add from server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/)

Also works. But if the images are more than 25k-1lakh then these plugins wont help you. If anybody knows update here thanks.