# How to upload images to WP Panel keeping correct folder in FTP

Tags: plugins, images, media, directory

I've uploaded an 'Uploads' folder to my FTP this folder has other folders like 2015, 2016, 2017 and inside them some images.

I wanna know if is there some way or plugin to make all my images show in WP Panel (wp-admin) and keeping the exactly same struture URL that i've uploaded in ftp.

i've tested an plugin but when it register the image, the image goes to another folder 2018/03 :(

Any help?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Media from FTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-from-ftp/), or potentially also have a look at [Add From Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) (though that one hasn't been updated for a while), as mentioned in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218813/92750).